# Monetization Manager - App URL has already been claimed"

Tags: facebook, ironsource, facebook-business-manager

I previously had a property and a linked Android app in my Monetization Manager account, but I removed it due to a problem. Now I created a new property in this same Monetization Manager account. When I try to add the same Android app to the new property, I get the error "App URL has already been claimed". This is because I had added the app to the old property which I deleted. How can I solve this?

I had also tried restoring deleted app/property to unlink the app but the restored app shows no property.

Answer (score 2):

Currently facing the same problem. Meta support tells you to delete any duplicate links which might be claiming your page.

I changed that too. But seems like I am getting the same error. Maybe you can try once to see all your content is under one business account  {eg, page, insta handle , whats app handle etc}

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a bug at Facebook (that was reported by many users), when you delete the Application/Property something remains in their databases with a reference to your app somehow and it will prevent you from recreating your app with the same URL.

Here is what worked for me:

1. Delete the application, its property and all its related data.
2. Delete all related data, duplicates of the app from all admins, business.
3. Try to add the app again and check if adding the URL to the property works now.

If step (3) does not work immediately, repeat steps 1 and 2, wait for at least 12 hours or one business day and try again. in my case, It worked the next day when I tried adding it.

Comment: I have already wait for a month. it's still not working